# Should a tag be created for block themes?

Tags: feature-request

There is currently no [block-themes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/block-themes) tag. Would it be good to create one, or is it better use the combination of [theme-development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-development) and [block-editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/block-editor), or simply [theme-development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-development) by itself?

Just my own thoughts:
How common of a topic does "block themes" need to be to warrant its own tag? But also,
adding it might depend on the future of WordPress: If block themes become commonplace, then making a new tag for block themes may not be necessary. In that case, I could see a [classic-themes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classic-themes) tag becoming useful.

(I don't have enough rep to create a tag myself, though I wouldn't do it unless it made sense.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think this should be a tag